# C++ parameter pack access out of range

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

I'm kinda new to parameter pack and I ran into a problem related to out of range index. To simplify the problem, I want to access the n-th element (lets say 3rd) in parameter pack inside the function. If the function call does not pass 3 params (or more), return nullptr. Maybe there is a recursive solution to safely ignore the case of less parameters?

```
template <int I, class... Ts>
decltype(auto) get_element(Ts&&... ts) {
    return std::get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(ts...));
}

    template <typename... Args>
    void foo(Args ... args)
    {
        auto p = get_element<3>(args...);
    }


int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Error   C2338   tuple index out of bounds
Error   C2672   'std::get': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: `foo` must be called with at least 3 params. U just provided 1.

Comment: @Red.Wave Please read the question carefully! nogoodatit is completely aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (since C++17)

```
template <int I, class... Ts>
  decltype(auto) get_element(Ts&&... ts) {
  if constexpr (I < sizeof...(Ts))
    return std::get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(ts...));
  else
    return nullptr;
}
```

Now you get only compiler warnings for unused parameters in doubt. That might be intented I think since you already bypassed compile time safety this way.

Also keep in mind that std::get is zero-based! So for a working example, you need not three but at least four parameters.

Comment: For the code suggested, I get error C2181: illegal else without matching if

Comment: Witch compiler do you use? Does it support C++17?

Comment: Looks like I don't have C++17 support (IT to blame) - Using VS2015
_MSC_VER : 1900
_MSC_FULL_VER : 190024215
_MSC_BUILD : 1
_MSVC_LANG : C++14

Comment: If C++17 is currently no option for you, a template meta counter is a way to go here for instance.

Comment: I'm trying linux with gcc version 7.2.0 (GCC)
error: 'if constexpr' only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z [-Werror]